# How to send all objects in base object using WCF

Tags: c#, wcf, web-services

I am working on a project where i have to send data to server from client device using WCF. The project has a Model that is already developed. All classes in model are subclasses of SObject.

In synchronizing project i am doing the following.

```
    [ServiceContract]    
public interface IMobileService
{

    [OperationContract]
    SynchronizeResponse Synchronize(SynchronizeRequest request);

    [OperationContract]
    SynchronizeResponse Checkout(CheckoutRequest request);
}
```

and

```
    [DataContract]
public class SynchronizeResponse
{
    [DataMember]
    public bool FullSync { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public IEnumerable<Student> Students { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public IEnumerable<Teacher> Teachers { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public IEnumerable<SObject> SObject { get; set; }}
```

and same type of code for Class SynchronizeRequest

It works in that way. but how can i send just SObject that include all sub objects? i have tried [KnownType(typeof(Student))] in the SyncRequest attribute. but it throws exception.

without editing model, what is best way to accomplish the task.

Answer (score 0):

Try this: (The best I guess I can do since you didnt' supply all the definitions.

```
[DataContract]
[Serializable]
[KnownType(typeof(MyConcrete001))]
[KnownType(typeof(MyConcrete002))]
public abstract class SObject
{}
```

Comment: So my project has 53 classes. you mean i should write each class as knowtype on top of SObject? and that in Model?

Comment: Maybe you can use the example on this page with some reflection..?  Otherwise, I think you're correct and you'd have to explicitly list every expected type. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.serviceknowntypeattribute.aspx